# Accessing Lists Defined inside Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

When running the code it asks for input according to plan, however the list alpha is not defined.

First the input did not read so I changed the indentations so that it did, however the defining issue is not solved.

```
def newclassification1(alpha,bravo):
        alpha = ["Jacob", "Jane", "Jim"]
        bravo = ["Male", "Female", "Unknown"]

    name = input("What is the persons name?")
    if name in alpha:
        while True:
            print(bravo[alpha.index(name)])
    else:
        print("The persons name is not in the register.")
```

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 7, in
>    NameError: name 'alpha' is not defined

Comment: To clarify: def newclassification1(alpha,bravo):
        alpha = ["Jacob", "Jane", "Jim"] ;
        bravo = ["Male", "Female", "Unknown"] ;

Comment: Why do you have `alpha` and `bravo` as function arguments and then assign values to each of them as the first step inside your function?

Comment: The indentation is still broken (but now a combination of the original code and benvc's attempt at fixing it).

Comment: Dont know im a n00b.

Comment: If you really want to (re)define the structures inside the function, you can assign them default values to None in the arguments, like ```def newclassification1(alpha = None, bravo = None)```

Answer (score 0):

I made some adjustments, the main is removing alpha and bravo from the function.

```
alpha = ["Jacob", "Jane", "Jim"]
bravo = ["Male", "Female", "Unknown"]
def newclassification1(alpha,bravo):
    name = input("What is the persons name?")
    if name in alpha:
        print(bravo[alpha.index(name)])
    else:
        print("The persons name is not in the register.")
newclassification1(alpha,bravo)
```

This works, because since you are passing alpha and bravo to the function, these variables should be defined outside the function. Also I changed your `while` into an `if` because otherwise, you would get infinite outputs.
Output for the function I'm sharing:

```
What is the persons name?Jim
Unknown
What is the persons name?Jane
Female
What is the persons name?a
The persons name is not in the register.
```

Given OPs comment: `alpha` and `bravo` ***must*** be defined within the fucntion.

```
def newclassification1(alpha = [],bravo = []):
    alpha = ["Jacob", "Jane", "Jim"]
    bravo = ["Male", "Female", "Unknown"]
    name = input("What is the persons name?")
    if name in alpha:
        print(bravo[alpha.index(name)])
    else:
        print("The persons name is not in the register.")
newclassification1()
```

Output:

```
What is the persons name?Jim
Unknown
What is the persons name?Tim
The persons name is not in the register.
What is the persons name?Jane
Female
```

Comment: What's with the `if True:` tho, you need to remove it. Just because op has incorrect code you don't need a filler for that, when you are writing answers you should just delete the unnecessary code.

Comment: You are right, I wasn't paying attention to the whole code, just saw the issue with the while and thought it was a condition that was to be applied once, so changed it to an `if` without checking that there was an `if` in the line above!

Comment: @Celius Stingher; Global variables arent allowed thats why I had the lists inside the function. How would you solve it with the list in the same function alternatively making a separate function for the list and then call that function when needed.

Comment: What you can do is start by passing `lists` as optional arguments. Check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your final purpose but these two codes work without any errors on **Python3**.

The first one:

```
def newclassification1(alpha,bravo):
    name = input("What is the persons name?")
    if name in alpha:
        while True:
            print(bravo[alpha.index(name)])
    else:
        print("The persons name is not in the register.")

newclassification1(["Jacob", "Jane", "Jim"], ["Male", "Female", "Unknown"])
```

The second one:

```
def newclassification1(alpha,bravo):
    alpha = ["Jacob", "Jane", "Jim"]
    bravo = ["Male", "Female", "Unknown"]
    name = input("What is the persons name?")
    if name in alpha:
        while True:
            print(bravo[alpha.index(name)])
    else:
        print("The persons name is not in the register.")

newclassification1([], [])
```

Comment: Careful with the while loop, it prints an infinite repetition.

Answer (score 0):

```
def newclassification1(name):
    alpha = ["Jacob", "Jane", "Jim"]
    bravo = ["Male", "Female", "Unknown"]
    if name in alpha:
        print(bravo[alpha.index(name)])
    else:
        print("The persons name is not in the register.")

name = input("What is the persons name?")

newclassification1(name)
```

Comment: You should probably add some explanation to your answer to explain what you did to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by the other people, you should fix the indentation, as well as figure out something with your arguments.
First of all, when you define `alpha` and `bravo` in the function, each time it is called they will be rewritten, which I suppose you don't want to happen.
Secondly, you should fix the indentation. I suggest to have the following:

```
def newclassification1(alpha=["Jacob", "Jane", "Jim"],bravo=["Male", "Female", "Unknown"]):
        name = input("What is the persons name?")
        if name in alpha:
            print(bravo[alpha.index(name)])
        else:
            print("The persons name is not in the register.")
```

This way, by default you will be using your `alpha=["Jacob", "Jane", "Jim"]` and `bravo=["Male", "Female", "Unknown"]` but easily change it to whatever you want later when you call the function.

Also, you don't need a `while True` part as it will run without stopping the execution

Answer (score 0):

Extending Celius answer:

```
alpha = ["Jacob", "Jane", "Jim"]
bravo = ["Male", "Female", "Unknown"]
def newclassification1(alpha,bravo):
    name = input("What is the persons name?")
    print(bravo[alpha.index(name)] if (name in alpha) else "xxxxx")
newclassification1(alpha,bravo)
```

Just using Python ternary operation and sending result directly to print statement